# How to terminate all running threads when one fails, else complete all the threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am running multiple threads using threading in Python and I want to terminate all the threads if one fails. If none of them fails, it should continue executing the main thread. I have tried many approaches but none of them seems to be working fine.

It would be helpful if anyone can share how we should handle the scenario.

Comment: See [Different ways to kill a Thread](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/).

Comment: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook/0596001673/ch06s03.html

Comment: or use concurrent.futures instead of threading

Comment: can you help me to fix the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539729/python-process-increase-memory-when-using-threadpool-and-cv2